# How to align an image to the bottom of the div using flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent container with some child elements within such as the paragraph with various height based on the content. I'm trying to align an image to the bottom on the vertical axis using `justify-self: flex-end`, so it doesn't affect the other items within the parent container and put the image to the bottom of the parent container, but it doesn't work.

However, when I use `justify-content: flex-end`, it worked and pushed the entire content to the bottom, but I only want just the image to be aligned to the bottom. What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this?

```css
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
}
.parent-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 10px;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
    flex: 1;
}
.img-container {
    justify-self: flex-end;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>header 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>header 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/upay1rod/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment justify-content: flex-end; and add margin-top: auto on the img container

```css
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
}
.parent-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 1;
}
.img-container {
    margin-top: auto;  /* added */
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div>
    <h3>header 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>header 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>header 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `h3` and `p` in `div` container and add add `justify-content: space-between;` to `.parent-container > div`:

CSS:

```
.parent-container {
    display: flex;
}

.parent-container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>header 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>header 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
                sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>header 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
                sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-container">
            <img src="https://place-hold.it/300x500">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply change your CSS then it works. I added `heigh:100%;`, uncommented the `justify-content:flex-end;` and reassigned `.parent-container > div` to `div.img-container`:

```
    .parent-container {
        display: flex;
    }

    div.img-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 0 10px;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 1;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        justify-self: flex-end;
    }
```